# RDS IOPS utilizing fully

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have upgraded RDS mysql to 1000 IOPS from 120 IOPS, But same database operations utilizing more than 1000 IOPS now. Is there any way to implement RDS cluster or Is it possible to make use of lambda to reduce the usage of IOPS and load?

Newbie here, If anything wrong please suggest the right way. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

First try to review current caching parameter values.
Then check list in [AuroraMySQL.Reference.ParameterGroups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Reference.html#AuroraMySQL.Reference.ParameterGroups)
And try to tune/increase caching parameters like *query_cache_size*

Alternative solution is to use architecture redesign with [AWS CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html) to reduce load on primary system (probbly web?).